# Mule Rest Post call to SFDC to create a lead

Tags: rest, mule

I need to post a Rest call to SFDC with the respective credentials and create the SalesLead in SFDC. The response should come inthe form of Acknowledgment JSON response.
I am not sure how to use http:rest-service-component to post the data for creating lead.
Any help or sample is appreciated...

Comment: Why not using the SDFC connector?

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved now by using the "https:outbound-endpoint". All this code need is a JSON object as input.

Below is the snippnet:

```
<https:outbound-endpoint
        method="POST" exchange-pattern="request-response"
        address="url"
        contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP" >
        <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound"> 
        <add-message-property key="Authorization" value="OAuth ****"/>
        </message-properties-transformer> 
         </https:outbound-endpoint>     
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
```